# Cómo concatenar varias iteraciones en una misma linea en python

Tags: python-3.x

Estoy creando un script en el cual debo devolver las permutaciones posibles de una cadena de carácteres (Utilizo el método "permutations" de "itertools").

```
from itertools import permutations
```

Pero para ello debo imprimir todas las permutaciones en grupos de dos elementos concatenados en una misma línea. Mi código es el siguiente:

```
def permutations_iter(k):

inp_list = []
characters = "',[]()"
for i in k:
    inp_list.append(str(i))

sep = (list(permutations(inp_list, r=2)))
sep = str(sep).upper()
for x in range(len(characters)):
    sep = sep.replace(characters[x], "")
for i in sep:
    print(i, end="")

permutations_iter("achk")
```

Creo la variable "characters"

```
characters = "',[]()"
```

Para decirle que elimine los caracteres que no quiero imprimir

```
for x in range(len(characters)):
    sep = sep.replace(characters[x], "")
```

Sin embargo, cuando imprimo las permutaciones me retorna todos los elementos en una misma línea, y quiero que haga un salto de línea cada dos elementos de la permutación, como en el siguiente ejemplo:

[image: challenges/itertools-permutations/problem]

¿Cómo puedo lograr lo mismo?

Se agradece cualquier respuesta de antemano, valgo aclarar que soy nuevo en la comunidad y por lo tanto preguntando :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

En vez de convertir la `tupla` a `str` y remplazar los parentesis y coma, es mejor si usas `__.join()` para unir los elementos de la `tupla`.

```py
from itertools import permutations

iterator=permutations('achk',2)

for p in iterator:
    print("".join(p))
```

produce:

```
ac
ah
ak
ca
ch
ck
ha
hc
hk
ka
kc
kh
```

Puedes usar `__.upper()`; al comienzo, `...permutations('ACHK',2)`; o al final, `...print("".join(p).upper())`

Answer (score 1):

Puedes usar un for que avance de a 2:

```
for i in range(0, len(sep), 2):
    print(sep[i] + sep[i+1])
```

Nota: Esto va a dar error si `sep` tiene longitud impar